# Mono For Android MapsAndLocationDemo

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have Mono for Android trial version and am having some trouble with the MapsAndLocation demo.

I start up the emulator, yet when I select 'Run->Start Without Debuggin', I get the following error:

> C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Xamarin\MapsAndLocationDemo\xamarin-monodroid-samples-d76baf3\MapsAndLocationDemo\obj\Debug\android\src\mapsandlocationdemo\MapWithOverlayActivity.java(33,33): Error:  package com.google.android.maps does not exist

```
extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
```

As well as another 20 errors.

What do I need to fix this situation. Do I need to install an additional package? If so, what is it, and where can I find it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure you are deploying to an emulator that targets Google APIs.

To do this create a new emulator in the Android Virtual Device Manager and change the target from "Android 2.2 - API Level 8" to Google API eg. "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 16".

If you cannot see any Google API targets you will need to install one by using the Android SDK manager.

Comment: OK. Just getting the new SDK now and downloading the required Google API files.

Comment: I have downloaded the new SDK, and then installed the Google API files. However, when I load up the SDK manager from the start menu, the old SDK is still there that does not have the new Google API files. Do I need to remove this old SDK Manager and then install the new one, or can I link the new SD manager to be the default SDK?

Comment: Please make sure that in SDK manager that one of the Google APIs items is marked as 'Installed'. This image will show you what I am talking about. http://snag.gy/tHDYL.jpg

Comment: Once you have that installed then you can create a new emulator by going to Tools -> Manage AVDs... -> New... and enter in details similar to this http://snag.gy/tIPoW.jpg Once you have done this simply deploy to the new emulator